# Rails functions inside html

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following function inside an `html.erb` file and it is returning `syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end` error.

```
<% def my_func(obj)
    if obj === 'one'
        return 'one_class'
    elsif obj === 'two'
        return 'two_class'
end %>

<div class="<%= my_func('one') %>"></div>
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: You need to move your function in `helpers`. That's where they should reside.

Comment: You have methods in view file 0_o

Comment: You should never define functions in your views. It is against the whole idea of MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I observe that one more `end` is needed in your code.

```
<% 
  def my_func(obj)
    if obj === 'one'
        return 'one_class'
    elsif obj === 'two'
        return 'two_class'
    end
  end
%>

<div class="<%= my_func('one') %>"></div>
```

However, Please write this kind of methods in helper files. It makes more clear to your code and easy to maintain. See Rails helpers concept.

Answer (score 0):

Your function/method has expecting `end` at the end, however, I strongly recommend to avoid defining method in views. You should move your methods into helper and call it in views.

Your view:

```
<div class="<%= my_func('one') %>"></div>
```

Your corresponding helper:

```
def my_func(obj)
  if obj === 'one'
    'one_class'
  elsif obj === 'two'
    'two_class'
  end
end
```